# Why Android TV emulator API 23 (Android 6.0) have no network connection?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-tv

I just update the SDK to Android 6.0, and try to create a new AVD for TV emulator on API 23.

But sadly it return error:

> unable to resolve host "< myURL >": no address associated with hostname ...

My TV App is working fine and no connection problem in API MNC Android M (preview) emulator.

Is it the TV emulator in API 23 (Android 6.0) have problem? Or am I missing some code?

Answer (score 0):

Google released a new update for API23_x86 and API23_arm emulators. This problem was solved.